# list of object bind to another list of object

Tags: c#, linq

I have following classes,

```
public class Sample
{
 public int id { get; set;}

 public string name { get; set;}

}

public class SampleViewModel
{
 public int id { get; set;}

 public string name { get; set;}

}
```

and in Data access layer I'm getting list of object using Entity frameworks as follows

```
public class DAL
{
    Dbcontext db = new Dbcontext();

    public List<Sample> GetAll()
    { 
        var sp = db.Samples.ToList();  
        return sp;  
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to bind that object to another type of objects but with same properties, without using loop like follows

```
public class BL
{
    public List<SampleViewModel> GetAllSamples()
    {
        DAL data = new DAL();               
        var sam = data.GetAll();

        List<SampleViewModel> viewdata = new List<SampleViewModel>();

        viewdata = sam;

        return viewdata;
    }
}
```

but here I'm getting following error

in this line `viewdata = sam;`

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<Sample>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<SampleViewModel>`

what the correct way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `List<T>` is not the same as a `List<U>` meaning `data.GetAll()` returns a list with items of type `Sample` but `viewdata` is a list of items of type `SampleViewModel` - therefore you get the exception.

Override the implicit operator to convert from the one to the other or use `.Select` to project the one to the other:

```
var viewdata = data.GetAll()
                   .Select(item => new SampleViewModel { id = item.id, name = item.name })
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to map the properties to the `Sample` class object to the object of type `SampleViewModel` as for compiler they both are different types though they have same properties, you can do:

```
List<SampleViewModel> viewdata = sam.Select(x=> new SampleViewModel
                                               { 
                                                 id = x.id,
                                                 name = x.name
                                                }).ToList();
```

or you can use the libraries like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) who can do the mapping for you once you define the mapping between types in the configuration of it.

We initialize the mapping like:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Sample, SampleViewModel>());
```

and then in the code whenever need the object can be converted to other type :

```
var sam = data.GetAll();
List<SampleViewModel> viewdata = mapper.Map<List<Sample>,List<SampleViewModel>>(sam);
```